# Tensor vs elementwise product notation

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, tensor-products

I am familiar with undergrad level linear algebra, but we have not covered neither tensors nor anything more algebraic than a matrix/dot product. I do perfectly understand what an elementwise product means, but I don't have experience with Kronecker product, tensor product etc. So I need some help clarifying the relevant notation and notions.

While reading [the paper introducing GLU](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08083v3) I've come accross a notation $a\otimes b$ where $a$ and $b$ apparently are two vectors and $\otimes$ is the elementwise product. Yet, from what I recall that $\otimes$ used to denote Kronecker product, which as little as I am familiar with it still differs significantly from the elementwise product. If I google though, I see that $\otimes$ also [denotes the tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product).

I perfectly understand that we only have that many TeX symbols (actually, quite some of them), and if a paper clearly states that $\otimes, \times, \cdot,+, *$ or even $-$ is the elementwise product there, then they have all the rights to use that. Yet, I guess using say $-$ will be very confusing as it usually means subtraction, $+$ addition, $*$ convolution etc.

My question hence is: is $\otimes$ indeed often used in tensor algebra to denote elementwise products?

Comment: This is bad notation for the elementwise product. Nearly always it means the tensor / Kronecker product.

Comment: $\otimes$ should only be used to refer to the original meaning of tensor product, i.e., the universal bilinear form. But in certain cases where matrices are used instead of abstract vector spaces, tensor product can be constructed by matrices through some isomorphism rules. So you'd also see $\otimes$ used for matrices. For elementwise product, I have only seen $\otimes$ used in AI literatures, not in math literatures.

Comment: The elementwise product is named after [Jaques Hadamard and Issai Schur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) and denoted by $\circ$ or $\odot\,.$